# Image gets stretched when jQuery menu slides out on the iPad

Tags: jquery, ipad

I'm using this docking menu (http://www.jankoatwarpspeed.com/examples/AdvancedDocking/) with some small changes and running into an issue with the left menu stretching to the size of the 'dock' menu. I can only recreated it on the iPad and not with any browser on a pc. One odd part is that the entire left tab menu gets stretched out and not just the tab that is being hovered on. I'm fairly new to jQuery so I'm sure of its impact but haven't found this issue when looking around.

Any help is appreciated

(see image below)

[image: Photograph of iPad with horribly stretched menu]

Comment: You can take pictures on an iPad by pressing the circle button and the power button at the same time. Just so you know :D

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Figured it out. The z-index on the slide-out menu was lower than the tabs which doesn't cause an issue anywhere else except the iPad. On the iPad the higher image (the tabs) basically stretches across both layers.

To fix it I simply gave the slide-out menu higher z so that it is always in front. It doesn't have the same aesthetic but is pretty close.